# How to return an array when an object comes from the server?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using this structure -
return (details['home_store'] as List).map((e) => DetailsModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
When I receive data from the server in this format -

```
{
   "homestore": [
     {
       "id": 1,
     },
   ]
}
```

And what should I do when the data comes in this format?

```
{
       "id": 1,
     },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
DetailsModel.fromJson(details)
```

Or if you have several elements

```
class DetailsModel {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final String age;

  DetailsModel({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.age,
  });

  factory DetailsModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> details) {
    return DetailsModel(
      id: details['id'],
      name: details['name'],
      age: details['age'],
    );
  }
}
```

Just edit your Model class. You can add more fields to it.

Comment: Ok, And if there are several elements, for example, name, age?

Comment: I do. But I have a problem with how do I get the id? After all, I can not exclude so - details.id . But, I do like this - details[index].id . But the problem is that I don't output to a list and I don't have an index. How to be?

Comment: Try details['id']

Comment: That doesn't work. I can't apply like that.
- The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'.
I try to use details['id'].toString() but the error stays the same

Comment: Ok well if id is a int try change the type of the variable from string to int in your model class, then it should work

Comment: You will be surprised, but in the model I have an id - like a string

Comment: Yes you have to make id a final int id and not final String id

Comment: I understood what the problem was, I was able to address it like this - details[5]. Is it correct?

Comment: Is details a List<Map> or just a Map? Because you cant access fields inside of a map by putting a number inside of these square brackets, or yes?

Comment: details its map - return (details as List).map((e) => DetailsModel.fromJson(e)).toList();

Comment: No its a list because you put .toList() at the end, so then you can access it by details[index_here]

Comment: Yes, it really helped me. Thanks for helping me figure it out, I'm just a beginner and decided to ditch the spaghetti code at an early stage

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247962/discussion-between-daniil-and-code-master).